# i have a bootstrap left side menu ..but when i click the menu items i want to dispaly content from particular nav item on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
            <div class="profile-usermenu">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" id="navitem1" data-content="content-wrap1 ">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                        View Profile </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" id="navitem2" data-content="content-wrap2">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-"></i>
                        Account Settings </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" id="navitem3" data-content="content-wrap3">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        Tasks </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" id="navitem4" data-content="content-wrap4">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
                        Help </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- END MENU -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="profile-content">
          <div id="content-wrap1" class="content">Edit Profile Content goes here Either it may form or what ever </div>
          <div id="content-wrap2" class="content">Account settings</div>
          <div id="content-wrap3" class="content">Invoices</div>
          <div id="content-wrap4" class="content">Credit card info</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  <br>
<br>
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zai4O.png           Click link for image

Comment: create a jsfiddle with your problem and explain it better.

Comment: when i click nav items i want to dsplay  content just beside the menu :)

Comment: notg i dont no buddy how to do ..it

Comment: above link image to see my page    .......same like fb left menu